# Extract Data with Selenium and VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new using selenium. I have a site that is not more compatible with the IE, so i decided to try this new technique, but can't see what is wrong on my code. Any help will be apreciated.

```
 Sub ExtractPrice()
    
        Dim bot As WebDriver, myproducts As WebElements, myproduct As WebElement
        Set bot = New WebDriver
        bot.Start "chrome"
        bot.Get "https://www.veadigital.com.ar/prod/72060/lechuga-capuchina-por-kg"
    '    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
        Set myproducts = bot.FindElementsByClass("datos-producto-container")
    '
    For Each myproduct In myproducts
    If myproduct.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text <> "" Then
    'Debug.Print myproducts.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text
        Worksheets("VEA").Range("b2").Value = myproducts.FindElementsByClass("product-price").Text
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox ("complete")
    End Sub
```

Comment: But what is the issue ? What error message you are getting ?

Comment: `Worksheets("VEA").Range("b2").Value`  is hard coded to b2?  - as you go through the loop you'll forever write to that cell...  Beyond that you need to describe what is happening and what you expec to happen with enought supporting information for us to understand your problem.

Comment: Mr Rich, It suppose that if it works it should give me the price (that is what i need), wich is under class 'product-price', but it don't. I just want this element, but if the problem would be the 'b2' it should bring it anyay on debbuging and also it bring me nothing

Comment: @ rahul rai, no error, just doesn't bring any data

Comment: It seems synchronization issue.You need provide some explicit wait before interaction the element.`Set myproducts = bot.FindElementsByClass("datos-producto-container")`

Comment: If you refer to add:  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")    i did, but anyway give me an error 'the object doesn't admit this methd or properties'

Comment: Added 'bot.Wait 5000' but same error

Comment: With explicit wait it is working fine using Selenium python.Increase you wait time to 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in this line :

```
Worksheets("VEA").Range("b2").Value = myproducts.FindElementsByClass("product-price").Text
```

Remember **FindElements**, returns a list of webelements rather than webelement. Instaead use the line you have used in if condition.

```
Worksheets("VEA").Range("b2").Value=myproduct.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text
```

**`Note :`** With above line of code you will get your price, but it will come as **$379** instead of $3.79. As there is no . in price on page. Better way to store price is :

```
Dim intValue = myproduct.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text
Dim decValue=   myproduct.findElementByXPath(".//div[@class='product-price']//span").Text
Worksheets("VEA").Range("b2").Value = Replace(intValue , decValue, "."&decValue)
```

Above will assign **$3.79.**

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can't make it bring me the price data, i tried both method you gave me. The price is $92, no decimals today, i don't know if it could complicate and the first method maybe something is wrong on my code.

Comment: In the Edit you suggested i can still see you are using **myproducts**.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text instead of **myproduct**.FindElementByClass("product-price").Text. Please note here myproducts refer to a list here and myproduct to a webelement. Please try with exact code.

Comment: Dear Rahul. thank you for your help. I finally could do it with your suggestions. One thing i can't understand, there are some links that if you entry manual show a price, wich is the true price and entering by the scrypt it shows a very different price an if you try fast to inspect before  the url get closed it come from the same div class, it happen only with some products, What could be happening? i will give you and example    https://www.veadigital.com.ar/prod/109704/mandarina-promocion

Comment: Could be a way to protect from scryps that this url have? Showing manual one web and other for scrypts? But it occur only with some products, this is what confuse me

Comment: @Marina Sure I will have a look and try to replicate your issue. Just one suggestions. If your original issue is resolved please accept and upvote as token of appreciation. Thanks and cheers !!!

Comment: Of course...I have  clicked at the up arrow, not sure if it's the   way to upvote, other case let me know. And  also if you take a look for site. I always use the IE and MSXML2 for scraping, but this site started to fail with both, is for this reason y tried with chrome, but it seems to fail too as it show a different price, so not way....do you think about a method could do it? as phyton for ex, or if the site  have a detection for scypts it will fail with every method?

Comment: @MarinaMontero Regrading your issue with manual url giving different rate and and automation script giving different. It should not be the case. As i have tried with URL veadigital.com.ar/prod/109704/mandarina-promocion and i got same rate in both case $15.99. For second issue where it is failing exactly as until unless these is some chnage in HTML DOM it should not fail. Also most important **As a pratice on Stack overflow** once original issue is resolved you should accept / upvote the answer**. For New problem you should start a new thread by posting a fresh question. Cheers!!!

Comment: I have run the script again and getting price so please ask a fresh question if you are getting any other issue. Happy to help and learn.  Please see below linkfor your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. It didn't work for me until i add  bot.AddArgument "--headless"  , now it show me the true prices.

Comment: Great happy to help mate. :)